# Money Transfer to UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, india, real-estate, international-transfer

I bought a holiday apartment in Goa some years ago. I had an NRI account. The bank then changed it to an NRO savings account.
I sold it three years ago and the money was paid into this account.
I wish to transfer this money to my UK account.
My bank (Axis) said I need proof of the purchase money coming from UK, and they would sort it.
However, the bank has done nothing for over three years even though I have sent them all the proof they need many times and now ignore my e-mails.
I have  a visa and PAN card.
How can I transfer my money?

Comment: What is an NRI account? The standard names are NRE and NRO. If you were once a resident of India and had an ordinary bank account in India, it would be converted to an NRO account when you moved to the UK and became an NRI. If you paid for the holiday apartment from the NRO account or from the savings account before it was converted into an NRO account, then you didn't pay for it via funds transferred from the UK "proof of purchase money coming from UK" even if you were an NRI and bought the apartment while you were a resident of UK; you bought it with money you already had in India. continued

Comment: If by NRI account you meant an NRE account (which can only hold money that has been sent to India from abroad), then you have the necessary proof that you bought the holiday apartment using money sent from abroad, even if some time elapsed between deposit of the money and withdrawal to buy the apartment. But your Indian bank had no business changing the status of the account from NRE to NRO. It is correct that the proceeds from the sale of the apartment are deposited into an NRO. Y account.

Comment: Re; Purchase of Apartment. I paid for the apartment from my UK account and UK credit card. I only opened my first India  account after completion of purchase to facilitate payments to site admin .Bills etc Then moved my account to Axis which was local (Goa).